# Orthogonal Subspaces and subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the relationship between $V^\perp \cap W^\perp $  and $V \cap W $?

Suppose that $ V $ and $ W $ are subspaces of a vector space $U$. If $V \cap W $ is zero then there is non zero vector in $V^\perp \cap W^\perp $.

I just want to know whether my assumption is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: What about the subspaces $y=0$ and $x=y$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$? Surely the intersection is just the $0$ vector. But the intersection of the orthogonal complement is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with subspaces $V=\{v=(x,y)| y=0\}$ and $W=\{w=(x,y)|x=y\}$. Then $V\cap W=\{0\}$. But $V^\perp=\{v'=(x',y')|v\cdot v'=0\}=\{v'|x'x=0\}$. This can only be true if $x=0$ or $x'=0$. Then $V^\perp =\{ (x',y')| x'=0\}$. Now $W^\perp =\{ w'=(x',y') | x'x+y'x=0\}=\{w'|x(x'+y')=0\}$. So either $x=0$ or $x'+y'=0$.

Suppose $u\in V^\perp \cap W^\perp$. Then $u=(x,y)$ such that $x+y=0$ and $x=0$. But this means $y=0$. Therefore, $u=(0,0)$. A counterexample!

Goodluck